# How opensea auction smart contract work without storing the ether

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, opensea

Trying to understand how opensea "Make the bid" work. Whenever any interested buyer wants to buy an NFT, they have to create an offer,in which they basically sign a message(commitment)(which is not costing gas fees). I didn't understand how this thing works behind the scene. If, let say, i made an offer for 3 days and i won the bid or seller accepted the bid, and i don't have required ether(the bid amount) at that moment, then what will happen?

Auction smart contract basically take bidder amount as stake, and when auction end, if user doen't won the auction, transfer staked ether back, but in both the above process staking ether+paying transaction fees, these extra overhead is there.

Opensea doesn't follow staking of bidding amount and hence save user from paying transaction fees + staking ether. But they ask user to sign for confirmation of bid. Can anyone explain whats technically happening?

I have gone through below links also but this doesn't answer how opensea is working.

Link 1 : [Creating an auction smart contract without storing the ether](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102660/creating-an-auction-smart-contract-without-storing-the-ether)

Link 2: [Auction data on-chain or off-chain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110749/auction-data-on-chain-or-off-chain)

In link 2, they mention "Commitments are created by signing "messages". These are off-chain transactions. However, cancelling transactions requires posting on-chain." But how is it actually working?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @mdmb not exact answer. But i just have an idea how they are doing it

Comment: @DummyMail, Can you pls share if you have any solution